# How to add a new page in ASP.NET mvc4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to make a new project and I want to add a new page, using the Microsoft sample website as a starting point.  The Microsoft sample website already has an About and a Contact page.

How do I add a new page to the sample website using ASP.NET mvc4?

Comment: Since you're clearly new to MVC, I _strongly_ recommend you read through the official [ASP.NET MVC guide](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started) as it will answer most of the "newbie" questions you might have.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC you work with Models, Controllers and Views. Controllers are classes containing methods called Actions. Each Action is used as an entry point for a given user request. This Action will perform any necessary processing with the model and return a view. So basically you will start with defining a Controller (if not already done) and add Actions to it:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Then you right click on the Action name and select the Add->View option which will create a new View for the given Action in the respective `~/Views` folder.

I would recommend that you start by going through the basic tutorials here: http://asp.net/mvc

Comment: Thanks, that's the most concise explanation I've heard!